# Compass not finding singularitygs

Tags: ruby, sass, bundler, compass-sass, singularitygs

i feel like I've been doing this for about a week now!

if anyone could help that would be great, i just can't seam to import singularitygs

```
 error sass/app.sass (Line 2: File to import not found or unreadable: singularity's.
```

my app.sass

```
@import "compass"
@import "singularitygs"
@import "breakpoint"
@import "jacket"
@import "toolkit"
@import "bourbon"
// My sass
@import "partials/normalize"
```

my gem file

```
source "https://rubygems.org"

gem "compass", "~>1.0.0.alpha.17"
gem "sass", "~> 3.3.3"
gem "singularitygs", "~> 1.2.0"
gem "breakpoint", "~> 2.4.2"
gem "jacket", "~> 1.1.1"
gem "toolkit", "~> 2.0.1"
gem "bourbon", "~> 3.1.8"
```

bundler out put when running bundle update

```
Using sass (3.3.3)
Using thor (0.18.1)
Using bourbon (3.1.8)
Using chunky_png (1.3.0)
Using multi_json (1.9.1)
Using compass-core (1.0.0.alpha.19)
Using compass-import-once (1.0.4)
Using json (1.8.1)
Using rb-fsevent (0.9.4)
Using ffi (1.9.3)
Using rb-inotify (0.9.3)
Using rb-kqueue (0.2.2)
Using listen (1.1.6)
Using compass (1.0.0.alpha.19)
Using sassy-maps (0.3.2)
Using breakpoint (2.4.2)
Using jacket (1.1.1)
Using singularitygs (1.2.0)
Using toolkit (2.0.1)
Using bundler (1.5.3)
Your bundle is updated!
```

Comment: Please post your `config.rb`. Also, you seem to have posted a truncated error message. Please post the full one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you set your singularity gem to require in the config.rb file?

Comment: yeah require 'compass'
require 'singularitygs'
require 'breakpoint'
require 'jacket'
require 'toolkit'
require 'bourbon'

Comment: hmm and have you tried altering the order of your gem import statements? maybe try breakpoint and toolkit before singularity. cuz the rest looks fine to me.

Comment: i'm giving up now and going to bed i'm beat, thanks for your help - hopefully get it going in the morning finally

Comment: ok I've got it working just can't get the background-grid up going to do some searching on here, you were right i had to re-order my imports